# Docusign SDK check envelope status

Tags: docusignapi

Currently, I am having a schedule job which get all uncompleted envelope status from my system and check each envelope status update from docusign via docusign sdk **(Envelope env = envelopesApi.getEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId))**. The reason to use that api is there are different use cases for each envelope status.

But I see that polling api **(EnvelopesInformation envelopes = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(accountId, options))** has limitation that not allowed to poll DocuSign more than once every 15 minutes. I don't use this api now.

So is there any problems/limitation for **envelopesApi.getEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId))**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **getEnvelope()** and the **listStatusChanges()** requests both have the same polling limitation in place, if you start calling either too much your API key might get throttled or temporarily disabled by DocuSign.

However, since the **listStatusChanges()** request returns status on a whole set of envelopes instead of just one envelope at a time this is the preferred API request when polling the DocuSign platform.

Furthermore, the truly optimal option which doesn't count at all against the platform limits is using DocuSign webhooks to push status out to your app instead of your app constantly polling. You can configure webhooks either through the **DocuSign Connect** module or by using **eventNofications** through the envelope structure.

Learn more about [DocuSign Webhooks](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect).

Comment: Thank Ergin. So does that limitation once for 15 minutes on docusign accountId level, docusign credential level or envelopId level? I am asking because I have each evelopeId tie to different docusign credential or accountId?

Comment: The polling limit is on a per ENVELOPE basis, so once you poll an envelope you need to wait 15 mins before polling that same exact envelope again.  See the following guide for info on Resource/API limits:  https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/resource-limits

Comment: Thank Ergin. So if I pull one envelope status and check that it is rejected, then I pull recipients for that envelope to see who rejects the envelope. Both happen after one another. I think it's fine since envelope and recipient are 2 different routes. Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, since it's a different route this is acceptable and will not be flagged. If this answers your questions can you accept my answer?  Thx